# run 2nd jquery animation with the end of 1st animation

Tags: jquery-ui, animation

I created a simple js banner.
First a company name will run into the center from left and then fading in an image logo

html

```
   <div id="banner-container">
     <div id="companyname"><p>P.Classique Trading Co. Ltd.</p></div>
     <div id="logo"><img src="img/twitter_logo.png" width="100" height="100" /></div>
   </div>
```

css

```
#banner-container {
     position:relative;
    left:300px;
     top:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
     display:box;
  background-color: #282800;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

#companyname {
  position: relative;
  color:yellow;
  top:15px;
  left:-500px;
  font-family: 'Finger Paint', cursive;
}
#logo {
  position: relative;
  display:none;
  top:50px;
  left:200px;   
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left = $('#companyname').offset().left;
    $("#companyname").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"120px"}, {duration:1000, easing:'easeOutBounce'});

    $("#logo").fadeIn(1500);

    }

  );
```

the result is two animations start at the same time which is not I want to.

Answer (score 3):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jzVuC/2/)**

Use a callback for your animation:

```
$("#companyname")
    .css({left:left})
    .animate(
        {"left":"120px"},
        {
            duration:1000,
            easing:'easeOutBounce',

            complete: function () {
                $("#logo").fadeIn(1500);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhsWt/

You can use the second fadein as parameter for when first one finishes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var left = $('#companyname').offset().left;
$("#companyname").css({left:left}).animate({left:"120px"}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce',
   function() {
        $("#logo").fadeIn(1500);
    }
)});
```

Comment: I tried this syntax before I asked.
This is not working. The logo won't show.

Comment: It is the same solution as the one above that you said it worked. Also the fiddle shows it works fine. The logo doesn't show because the image is not there as specified in the css. I updated the fiddle with working image: http://jsfiddle.net/KhsWt/1/